# Pullback of euclidean metric on the disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

$\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}\newcommand{Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$Consider the biolomorphism $$f : D \to H$$ where $H$ is the complex upper hyperplane $\{\Im(z) > 0\}$ and $D$ is the unic disc, given by $$ f(z) = i \frac{1-z}{1+z}$$

I am trying to prove (and I could be terribly wrong) that if I pull back the euclidean metric on $H$ through $f$ I get:

$$f^*(dx \otimes dx + dy\otimes dy) = \frac{4}{|1+z|^4}(d \alpha \otimes d\alpha + d\beta \otimes d\beta)$$Here $z = \alpha + i \beta.$

In trying to prove this I am somehow stuck in calculations and actually get the wrong result... I procede as follows: $$f^*(dx \otimes dx + dy\otimes dy) = \left(\frac{\partial\Re(f)}{\partial \alpha} \right)^2 d \alpha \otimes d\alpha + \left(\frac{\partial \Im(f)}{\partial \beta} \right)^2d\beta \otimes d\beta.$$
 Now I use Cauchy Riemann equations to get: $$\frac{\partial \Im(f)}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\partial\Re(f)}{\partial \alpha} = 2 \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}} \right)$$

But now, since $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{i}{(1+z)^2}$ it seems to me that I do not get the desired result.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that because $f$ is holomorphic, writing $x+iy=w$,
\begin{align*}
f^*(dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy) &= \frac12 f^*(dw\otimes d\bar w+ d\bar w\otimes dw) = \frac12 |f'(z)|^2(dz\otimes d\bar z+d\bar z\otimes dz)\\ &= |f'(z)|^2 (d\alpha\otimes d\alpha+ d\beta\otimes d\beta).
\end{align*}
Your calculation of $f'(z)$ appears wrong: The answer should be $\dfrac{-2i}{(1+z)^2}$, and this gives the correct result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did many errors while trying to solve this exercise, and now I see that my questions is full of wrong caclulations. I was thinking about erasing the question, since it does not seem like it could be of use to anyone after me. I don´t know if this is considered a good idea on this forum.

Comment: Ordinarily, one should not remove a question once it's been answered. The question and answer may be of help to someone else.